# Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead

Tags: python, machine-learning

I don't know why the error occurs, and I've tried to reshape but no luck.

Thanks for answering.

```py
X_test = np.append(X_test, scaler.transform(working_data.iloc[-1][0]))
```

And here is the error message I receive.

```py
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=9583.994119999077.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

And the full code is here:https://activewizards.com/blog/bitcoin-price-forecasting-with-deep-learning-algorithms/

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Presumably, `working_data.iloc[-1][0]` is a scalar and thus requires reshape. Try `np.reshape(working_data.iloc[-1][0], (-1,1))` inside the `scaler.transform`

Answer (score 0):

It is a common error that happens while working with arrays in Python. So let's say you have an array

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

shape of this array will be (3,3). Now if you access `a[-1,0]` you will get `7`, which will have no shape as it's scalar. If you want to append this to an array say `[[2, 3, 4]]` this will not work, as latter is a 2-D array and for append to work, you need arrays of same dimension. So if you call reshape like this: `a[-1,0].reshape(-1,1)` then you will get an array of shape (1,1), that is instead of `7` you will get `[[7]]`. Another way to bypass this would be to access the value like this: `a[-1,:1]`, this essentially does the same thing as `a[-1,0]` but it indicates the array that you want the resulting array as 2-D.
Another thing to note will be to check the axis you are trying to append to, as I do not know the shape of X_test, I can not say you want to add a new row, or a new column, so keep that in mind in case that causes an error later.